# What are the major advantages of Microsoft virtualization products over other(Citrix, Vmware, IBM) virtualization products in the market?

Tags: virtualization

What are the major advantages of ***Microsoft virtualization*** products(hypervisor products) over any other(***Citrix, VMware, IBM***) virtualization products in the market ?

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be no technical or independently produced performance benefits of Hyper-V over ESX but if you're an MS house and are about to invest in Server 2008 then there are clear, and significant financial benefits in its favour.

I don't know Citrix or Xen/KVM well enough to answer for them.

Comment: Actually even knowledge advantages - if you are a MS shop, a hypervisor from MS is just a natural extension. All your patching is already in place, as is admin knowhow.

Answer (score 0):

**Hyper-V** with **App-V** and **XenDesktop** combined.

App-V provides more functionality when running with Hyper-V hosts than under VMware hosts. XenDesktop (Citrix) works with VMWare, but provides additional integration and features when combined with App-V and Hyper-V.

Aside from providing additional App-V and XenDesktop+App-V functionality then the advantages/disadvantages are negligible.

**From a dev/test point of view** it simply comes down if you need to support those environments for your customers or not. We use ESXi for our QA team but are investigating acquiring an Hyper-V/App-V/XenDesktop setup in addition as we have a growing number of customers trying to deploy and use our software in that environment.

(This question will get a better answer on SF instead of SO as it's not clear if the OP is talking about dev/test or production. As a deployment specialist I have to ensure dev supports these environments so it's kind of a grey area...)